# sql table structure to store an html select data

Tags: java, html, mysql, sql, database

I want to store a html select data in a table , like an option's value , it's text and some optgroup in between, *so that i can recreate `select` with least processing*

currently i have a setup of a two column table (`value<int>,text<varchar>`), i can't figure out how can i insert a blank optgroup?

the html select is like this -

```
<select name="height" id="height" class="sel_lng" required>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">v1</option>
        <option value="2">v2</option>
        <option value="3">v3</option>
        <option value="4">v4</option>
        <optgroup label="&nbsp;"></optgroup>
        <option value="5">v5</option>
        <option value="6">v6</option>
</select>
```

the table would look like

```
value   text
1       v1
2       v2
3       v3
4       v4 <-- i would like to add an optgroup after this row
5       v5
6       v6
```

Answer (score 0):

If values need to be sorted by number, you can just add float value 4.5, text NULL. On the front end replace all floating point numbers with `optgroup`.

Answer (score 0):

Option groups should contain the options they're grouping:

```
<optgroup>  
    <option>1<option>  
    <option>2<option>  
<optgroup>
```

So, I would think you can add a new table with value`<int>`, value`<int`> where column 1 is an arbitrary option group id and column 2 is the option id. If you would have items that don't belong to a group, simply don't add them to the option group table.

The new table would look like:
    opt_group_id, opt_id
    1, 5
    1, 6

HTH